# Does a "minimalist" or "minimalism" category exist in some formal well venerated design or art literature and what would be one or more examples?

Tags: terminology, history, minimalistic

Design or art forms I would personally categorize as minimalist would be:

- [Aniconism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aniconism): Especially, [Islamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aniconism_in_Islam) and perhaps also [late (and perhaps also early) Yahwistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahwism) and early Buddhist
- [Abstract art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_art): Especially [Abstract expressionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_expressionism) of the 50's
- Perhaps any **non** *[figurative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figurative_art)* art ; an extreme form would be line segment [tessellations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation) say of lines in different hues or colors as common in clothing design ([vertical example](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enTH852TH852&biw=1536&bih=722&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNSWxkRsxirvlMmNLI72XkFp1PtlBQ%3A1579533695346&sa=1&ei=f8UlXtHvFNOM4-EPzeSY4As&q=Striped%20Harem%20Pants%20men&oq=Striped%20Harem%20Pants%20men&gs_l=img.3...3876.4423..4578...0.0..0.131.626.3j3......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39j0i7i30j0i30.0milNPBM5aY&ved=0ahUKEwiRq8nGvZLnAhVTxjgGHU0yBrwQ4dUDCAc&uact=5#imgrc=ARiX5Q9ZWcDBZM:) ; [horizontal example](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimages-na.ssl-images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F61wuHlvOQWL._UX522_.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FMinimalist-Texture-Horizontal-Breathable-Printed%2Fdp%2FB07TR5MWXK&docid=Yc3LgnH3J3_9xM&tbnid=tjOBMBOg7GvJyM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjfnY71vJLnAhUHwzgGHULUCOEQMwhkKAcwBw..i&w=522&h=522&itg=1&bih=722&biw=1536&q=horizontal%20lines%20cotton%20pants&ved=0ahUKEwjfnY71vJLnAhUHwzgGHULUCOEQMwhkKAcwBw&iact=mrc&uact=8) ; [mixed example](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enTH852TH852&biw=1536&bih=722&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNSWxkRsxirvlMmNLI72XkFp1PtlBQ%3A1579533695346&sa=1&ei=f8UlXtHvFNOM4-EPzeSY4As&q=Striped%20Harem%20Pants%20men&oq=Striped%20Harem%20Pants%20men&gs_l=img.3...3876.4423..4578...0.0..0.131.626.3j3......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39j0i7i30j0i30.0milNPBM5aY&ved=0ahUKEwiRq8nGvZLnAhVTxjgGHU0yBrwQ4dUDCAc&uact=5#imgrc=Dwyjl7ePteWv8M:))
- Strict uniformity (as in clothing design - only front pockets `while` no back pockets) and so forth
- By the way --- music: Anhalt EBM, Moroccan Gnawa, Yemenite oud music

### My problem

I likely missed a few more possible examples or there is an existing, different term formally described and venerated, that might be different or doesn't include any of the examples I have given (these examples where given only to explain what might adjust with what I personally define *minimalist* (or *minimalism*) as there might be two ore more formal, venerated terms or schools of art).

### My question

Does a "minimalist" or "minimalism" category exist in some formal well venerated design or art literature and what would be one or more examples?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103915/discussion-on-question-by-johndoea-does-a-minimalist-or-minimalism-category).

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Bauhaus?</sub>

<sub>This is a minimalist answer.</sub>

Comment: Personally I would name Bauhaus architecture "heavy". Most of its buildings in Germany and Israel (architected by German Jewish architects) have become "white elephants" since the 50's and if at all exist in 2020, are decaying and disgusting; again, this is my personal opinion and you might mean something different than I do so sorry for any ill interpretation from my side.

Comment: @JohnDoea: I would say Bauhaus is pretend-minimalism: build only what you need for the practical use of the house, no ornamentation, nothing else. But in fact even the first houses by Le Corbusier were terribly unpractical: the roof leaked because it was flat, all the white gets dirty, the actual people who had to live in some Bauhaus houses added their own decoration and plants to give it some atmosphaere, etc.

Comment: Minimalism only works with *proportionally correct* design and ***accurate** execution*; unfortunately you missed the mark! Bauhaus as school and movement encompassed graphic design, typography & architecture; though it *trended* towards minimalism versus ornamentation in design ethos, it *also* had ties to de Stijl & earlier craft design. Gropius hoped to marry art, industrial design & industrial production: there wasn't the strong emphasis on minimalism as discrete æsthetic as many now think; the *International or Modern* movement, championed by Le Corbusier was *far closer* to minimalism.